# Conditional Causes Code to Fail

Tags: php

I am writing a small email-to-text script, and it seems that every time I wrap the "doMail()" function in an if-statement, it fails, or within the function, if I wrap the mail() function with an if-statement, it also fails.

However, if I remove the conditionals, it works like a charm?  What should I do and what could be the cause of this?

EDIT: By "...it fails," I mean it echoes "Something went wrong!" just as it should according to the code.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['doesExist'] == true) 
    {
        echo "Session doesn't exist!";
        die();
    }

if (!isset($_POST['num']) || !isset($_POST['carrier']) || !isset($_POST['msg'])) 
    {
        echo "Failed!";
        die();
    }

$num = $_POST['num'];
$car = $_POST['carrier'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$subject = '';
$head = 'From: admin@google.com' . "\r\n";

switch ($car)
    {
        case "att":
            $num .= "@txt.att.net";
            break;
        case "verizon":
            $num .= "@vtext.com";
            break;
        case "tmobile":
            $num .= "@tmomail.net";
            break;
    }

function doMail($toNum, $sub, $message, $headers)
    {
        if(mail($toNum, $sub, $message, $headers))
            {
                echo "Done!";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Something went wrong!";
            }
    }

doMail($num, $subject, $msg, $head);

?>
```

Comment: What happens when "it fails"?

Comment: It echoes "Something went wrong!" just as it should according to the code.  Sorry, I will edit that into the question.

Comment: So the mail gets sent only if you remove the conditionals? Doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: @kjetilh Yep! Doesn't make sense to me either!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($toNum, $sub, $message, $headers);` right before the mail call?

Comment: string(22) "<mynumber>@txt.att.net" string(0) "" string(7) "testing" string(24) "From: <myemail> "

Oh, and now it is reporting "Done!"

Comment: @DustinL. see this comment http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#109655 you may be having the same issue.

Comment: @crypticツ That's exactly the issue.  Thanks so much!  Throw that in an answer real quickly and I will accept it! :)

Comment: @DustinL. done, I do find it an odd issue, maybe it's dependent on the mail server used. PHP is likely returning the exit status code of the call to the mailserver, and said mailserver is maybe not providing any code at all so PHP returns nothing. Just a guess, I don't know the internal working of PHP =o)

Comment: A classic case of "scumbag PHP" indeed. :)  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently according to this [comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#109655) the `mail()` function may return an empty string instead of a boolean value of `TRUE` and as such will be evaluated as `FALSE` in a conditional statement as an empty value is considered `FALSE`.